# JAXBElement related question

Tags: jaxb

I am getting JSON String data like

{"username":"KU","password":"KU"}.

How to convert this string to JAXBElement object.

Please give me answer.

Comment: `JAXBElement` is for XML, not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) to unmarshal `JSON` easily. See the code below for your username and password case above. It outputs the following to the console console showing it has created an instance of the class from the `JSON` string.

`{"username":"KU","password":"KU"} -> Username [KU], Password [KU]`.

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class JaxbTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    String json = "{\"username\":\"KU\",\"password\":\"KU\"}";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JavaObject javaObject = mapper.readValue(json, JavaObject.class);

    System.out.println(json + " -> " + javaObject.toString());
  }

  private static class JavaObject {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public JavaObject() { }

    public String getUsername() {
      return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
      this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
      return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
      this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Username [" + this.username + "], Password [" + this.password + "]";
    }
  }
}
```